# Implementatin of queue in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Is it better to use linked list over arraylist for implementaion of Queue?
If I dequeue , the over load would be less in the case of liked list implementation?

Comment: Why not use one of the many implementations of [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)?

Comment: @Todd I dont want to use the queue..just want to implement it. Just Curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes to dequeue an element from the beginning of a LinkedList is less than from ArrayList.

This is because ArrayList is based on an array, and when a first element is removed all elements except the dequeued need to be shifted one position left. The greater the number of elements there is in ArrayList, the longer it will take.

In case of LinkedList, no matter how big the list is, there just constant number of references that should be updated in order to dequeue a first element.

Of course you can dequeue elements from the end of an ArrayList and it will take constant time (most of the time), but than addition of a new element (to the beginning) will require to shift all elements one position to the right.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a LikedList queue implementation in Java. I did not analyse the code but I would guess that a LinkedList if faster than an ArrayList in dequeuing an entry.